# Run kubectl patch statefulset in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, patch, kubectl, kubernetes-statefulset

I need to update statefulset using Jenkins. To be more precise, to update theme in init container.
This is the code that I use in Jenkins (it works fine in terminal):

```
kubectl patch statefulset test-deploy -n test -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"initContainers":[{"name": "theme", "image": "xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testrepo:latest"}]}}}}'
```

Error that I got: **expecting '}', found '-' @ line 293, column 192.
age": "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.am**

When I changed double quotes to single quotes:
kubectl patch statefulset keycloak-job-deploy -n ci-environment-dev -p '{'spec': {'template': {'spec':{'initContainers':[{'name': 'theme', 'image': '837236160124.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ci/keycloak-theme-thermo-fisher-develop:develop-0.0.1-3'}]}}}}'

I got this:

**Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 's' looking for beginning of object key string**

Can you please help me to realize what's wrong with quotes and what command I should use?

Comment: I find it much easier to work with `kubectl apply` instead of `patch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was related to screening in Groovy. This is the correct version:

```
kubectl patch statefulset test-deploy --namespace=${namespace} -p '{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"spec\":{\"initContainers\":[{\"name\": \"theme\", \"image\": \"${theme}\"}]}}}}'
```